# Using tox with shared code results in double dependency installation which ultimatly downgrades the dependency

Tags: python, tox

I have multiple modules in one repository. Now I would like to test the packaging for each module individually, while they might have dependencies between each other. Luckily I have found the dependency option using `{distshare}/}` in the documentation.

tox.ini:

```
[testenv]
deps =
    pytest
    {distshare}/pandas-ml-common-*.zip
```

Once I run `tox` it installs the local zip as one would expect. But since the dependency is also listed in the `setup.py` the module gets replaced by its older version from pypi. And yes you guessed it, this makes the tests fail. How can I avoid the installation from pypi once I have a dependency installed using distshare?

stdout:

```
(.venv) $ tox
GLOB sdist-make: /pandas-ml-utils/setup.py
py37 recreate: .tox/pandas_ml_common/py37
py37 installdeps: pytest, .tox/distshare/pandas-ml-common-0.2.0.zip
py37 inst: .tox/pandas_ml_common/.tmp/package/1/pandas-ml-utils-0.2.0.zip
py37 installed: cachetools==4.1.1,...,pandas-ml-common==0.1.15,...   <--- here it is again
```

EDIT:
from setup.py:

```
   packages=find_packages(),
   install_requires=["pandas-ml-common", *open("requirements.txt").read().splitlines()],
   extras_require={
      "dev": open("dev-requirements.txt").read().splitlines(),
   },
   include_package_data=True,
```

In the requirements.txt are only external dependencies like numpy (everything without version atm).

Comment: Why is it happening? Is `pandas-ml-common==0.2.0` out of the version range for `pandas-ml-utils-0.2.0`? Maybe show the `setup.py` file?

Comment: none of my depencies are versioned at all (until I reach a stable release). that is one of the many reasons I want to use tox. it always installs the latest depencies and I can fix broken test right away. ps 0.1.15 is the latest version on pypi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would maybe try something like:

```
[tox]
# ...

[testenv]
deps =
    pytest
    # omit "{distshare}/pandas-ml-common-*.zip"
commands_pre =
    python -m pip install {distshare}/pandas-ml-common-*.zip
# ...
```

Comment: indeed this works. but only with a fixed version, since wildcards are not supported

Comment: Would you mind trying `python -m pip install --no-index --find-links {distshare} pandas-ml-common`, and let me know if it does what you expect? If yes, I would update the answer.

Comment: But maybe you simply need to modify the `setup.py` for `pandas-ml-utils`.

Comment: right now I go with the fixed version, i have a version bump script anyway.

Comment: i have tried: `python -m pip install --no-index --find-links {distshare} pandas-ml-common` but it didn't make a difference. It installed from local file system and then overwrites with the old version from pypi

Comment: I guess, the version number found in this zip file is not in the range. No other cause comes to mind. Check the version numbers.

Comment: Maybe use something like `pipdeptree` inside the create test environment, to figure out what the dependency version ranges really are.